# How to read .dim (AutoCAD dimension style) in C#?

Tags: c#, autocad

Does anyone knows, how to read .dim (Auto CAD dimension style) in C#?

Comment: Please see http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-F8176D55-ED39-4FAA-93F7-D6E023C1DAD1 for C# example

Comment: adding to @labilbe comment, the DIMEX and DIMIM commands are part of Express Tools and just create ASCII files - https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-9DD96CAB-D7FE-4018-AA60-6309A2D4F6D3-htm.html

Comment: Thanks, for that information. but where do I specify file name of (.dim) file to read it through api?